# Layout broken across all websites in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, html

[image: Layout Broken]

Every websites layout is messed up. An example of BBC News can be seen above. I have attempted multiple troubleshooting methods recommended online such as uninstalling AdBlock however none of these have resulted in a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had disable styles checked